# Error during install via USB: Initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, 20.04, uefi

I'm in the process of dual booting the latest Ubuntu LTS release alongside my pre-existing Windows 10 install. I'm having a weird error when installing via USB: **Initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed**. I have been searching the web and have tried all manner of troubleshooting steps from others with the same error but nothing seems to fix it.

A picture of the error along with some graphical artefacts (the morse-esque dots look like they're meant to be more text). Down the bottom there are also some circles half cut off by the bottom of the monitor, although they're not captured here.

[image: Error with some graphical glitches]

I have tried:

- Disabling secure boot
- Disabling virtualisation support
- Removing any CPU/RAM overclocks
- Making sure SATA mode is AHCI
- Changing USB sticks
- Changing from USB 3 ports to USB 2 ports
- Making sure BitLocker is not enabled (for any drives)
- Using Rufus to write in both ISO and DD mode
- Changing Rufus' 'Partition scheme' setting from MBR to GPT
- Making sure CSM is disabled
- Making sure I'm booting in UEFI mode
- Checksum on the ISO

None of this has done anything. In fact, in some cases I get different errors - some MCE's complaining about the CPU - although now I can't seem to get it to do this again. As far as I'm aware there are no hardware issues though as I can boot into and use the Win 10 install just fine.

Lots of forum posts talk about changing the decompression settings in an initramfs config file but as I am installing and can't actually get into the OS yet I can't do this can I? This seems like a step to help those who are encountering this after a full install.

Specs:

- MOBO: ASUS ROG Strix X570-F Gaming
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3950x
- GPU: ROG Strix 2080ti
- RAM: 32GB DDR4 Corsair Vengeance
- PSU: Corsair 750W TXm Series

Comment: How are you writing the ISO to your USB drive? What are you using to do that?

Comment: @KGIII [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)

Comment: This is based on a variety of similar experiences and won't take you very long. Can you try again but use [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) and let us know if that works?

Comment: @KGIII exactly the same error sadly. Balena Etcher did give me an error about a checksum not matching at the end of its verification stage, but I checksummed a brand new ISO and flashed to a newly formatted USB and tried again just to get the same result.

Comment: I am at a loss. This is how you'd normally fix that error: `sudo sed -i ‘s/COMPRESS=lz4/COMPRESS=gzip/’ /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf && sudo update-initramfs -u` but that is useful only if the OS is installed. You *could* try editing that file on your USB, by way of a text editor. It should be in that same location on your USB. I do not know if that will work. Maybe someone will chime in.

Comment: I may be being stupid here, but the USB has just /efi/boot and three .efi files on it. Does not resemble the usual structure of a bootable USB as I'm used to seeing it. Let me flash again but not boot, I'll see what it leaves after a fresh flash, but may be the failing checksum at the end that reverts the drive back to being basically empty. Not sure - hang tight I'll test

Comment: @KGIII nope :) definitely only 3 files on that USB. Interestingly enough I did another USB just for the sake of completeness and that one did actually pass the checksum at the end, but still gave the same error. Not sure if this would shed any more light - but I can get to the live USB desktop if I click the 'safe graphics' option. This lets me do all but actually install the OS - it will get part way through and crash there too.

Comment: Try opening `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`  with a plain text editor and change `COMPRESS=lz4` to `COMPRESS=gzip`. Make sure it's a plain text editor and not something like Word. (I'm guessing you're using Windows.) If notepad is an option, that should work. I do not guarantee this works - but it's worth trying at this point. After this, I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: @KGIII I think we've crossed wires a little here so apologies! That file doesn't exist on the USB flashed by Balena. It has one root folder `/efi`, and, inside that, `/boot`. In there, there is `bootx64.efi`, `grubx64.efi` and `mmx64.efi`. Nothing else exists after the flash. I tried altering that file from within the live desktop on a previous flash but it rejected the save from vi because it's 'read only storage' apparently. No worries though, I'll wait for some other ideas, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115848/discussion-between-kgiii-and-reece-mercer).